# playing sound from localhost web site with javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

http://www.chatmic.com/dogs/sound/2.htm 
sound not working .. why ?

I took the example from 
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play9.htm

Comment: Using firebug you can see the path to your jquery librairies is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at you Javascript console:

```
GET http://www.chatmic.com/dogs/sound/jquery-1.4.1.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.chatmic.com/dogs/sound/jquery.svg.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: ok there is something wrong with the sound file .. I've tried different file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The jquery script you are including on your page is not found.